# Flickering with rapid changes in QStackedWidget index

Tags: qt, flicker, qglwidget

I developed an image visualization application in Qt using two QGLWidgets stored in a QStackedWidget. I want to be able to quickly display each QGLWidget in turn in order to spot differences in the two images considered. For that purpose, I mapped the `wheelEvent()` function to the `setCurrentIndex()` of the QStackedWidget.

My problem is that, when quickly triggering the `wheelEvent()` function, this results now and then in a white flickering which interferes with the image analysis task. It's like the default background of some widget is being displayed before displaying the QGLWidget, but I haven't been able to find which...

I am using C++ and Qt 4.7 with VisualStudio 2008, and the problem appears both on Windows XP and Windows 7.

Following is a minimal code reproducing the problem:

```
#include <QtGUI/QApplication>
#include <QtGUI/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGUI/QStackedWidget>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>

// Class for the QGLWidgets
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
public:
    int _id;
    // Constructor
    GLWidget(int id, QWidget *parent) :
        QGLWidget(parent),
        _id(id)
    {
    };
    // OpenGL initialization
    void initializeGL()
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);// Black Background
        glClearDepth(1.0f);                  // Depth Buffer Setup
    };
    // Paint in OpenGL viewport
    void paintGL()
    {
        // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer, and adapt viewport to widget geometry
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glViewport(0,0,geometry().width(),geometry().height());
        // Define projection matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0,1,0,1,-1,1);
        // Draw rectangle
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glColor4f((_id?0:1),0,(_id?1:0),1.0f);
        glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );
        glFrontFace(GL_CW);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex3f(0.33,0.33,0);
            glVertex3f(0.33,0.66,0);
            glVertex3f(0.66,0.66,0);
            glVertex3f(0.66,0.33,0);
        glEnd();
    };
};

// Class for the main window
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    QStackedWidget* _stack;
    GLWidget* _w1;
    GLWidget* _w2;

    // Constructor
    MainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0) :
        QMainWindow(parent,flags),
        _stack(NULL),
        _w1(NULL),
        _w2(NULL)
    {
        _stack = new QStackedWidget(this);
        _w1 = new GLWidget(0,_stack);
        _w2 = new GLWidget(1,_stack);
        _stack->addWidget(_w1);
        _stack->addWidget(_w2);
        setCentralWidget(_stack);
    };

protected:
    // Mouse wheel event switches between two GL widgets
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)
    {
        _stack->setCurrentIndex(1-_stack->currentIndex());
    };
};

// Main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.connect( &app, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()), &app, SLOT(quit()) );
    MainWindow mw;
    mw.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I tried to set the background color of all widgets involved to black (including the QMainWindow), using the code below, but the white flickering still occurs.

```
setAutoFillBackground(true);
QPalette pal = palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Window,Qt::black);
setPalette(pal);
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to remove this flickering ?

Comment: If you are using a `QStackedWidget` so only one image is visible at any time, wouldn't a cleaner solution be to render in two different contexts and switch between them? Then you can only have a single widget so these kind of problems disappear.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. However it is not clear form the documentation if changing the OpenGL context is possible after the constructor was called... How would you do that ? On the other hand, a consequence form this is that what is now two different classes with different roles (in my application) may need to be merged, resulting in a big ugly class. I'll look into that, but there should be some way to fix the flickering, am I wrong ?

Comment: Sorry I mixed my terminology there.  I would render to different framebuffers and the 'switching' just changes which one is used by the `QGLWidget` - the contexts may or may not change depending on how you are rendering.  I can't be sure without knowing your architecture, but surely you could keep your separate classes, but they paint onto framebuffers, and pass them to another class that actually performs the switching/displaying.  As far as fixing the flickering goes, you would first need to diagnose where the white colour is coming from...

Comment: ...  Your initial thoughts are the same as mine: either the fill colour of the `QGLWidget` or the `QStackedWidget` base colour - but you have checked both of those.  So you're going to have to do some experiments, perhaps try using just one `QGLWidget`, and connect your mouse wheel to show/hiding it; spin you wheel and see if it flickers white.  That should determine if it's the `QGLWidget` or `QStackedWidget`.

Comment: I'll do that. For now, I'm back on Windows XP and, strangely, the problem seems to have disappeared on its own ... I'll do some more tests if it comes back. Thanks anyway!